# Hide Specific Desktop Icons

Tags: icons, desktop, desktop-icons

I am looking for a way to hide icons that are placed on my desktop from Active Directory. I do not use these icons and want to declutter. If I delete or move them, my PC will restart during off-hours and Active Directory will redownload them to my desktop. Is there a safe, free software that can hide these icons?

Comment: Maybe provide a screenshot of the Icon. What you are wanting to delete seems more like an important program. You are in a business (Active Directory) so ask your IT Support about this.

Comment: It’s most likely you won’t be able to install any software without an admins permission also

Comment: The icons are just .url shortcuts. I am in IT but I do Networking/Telecom, whereas Client/Server handles Active Directory. I do have local admin access so I am able to install software myself. I just downloaded the original version of Fences (Fences_Public), which has a feature that allows you to hide/reveal specific icons upon double-clicking the desktop. If there is an alternative solution that will not reveal the icons upon double-click and doesn't lock my icons in-place, then I am open to trying it, otherwise Fences is working for me, minus the annoying locking of my icons.

Comment: You could create a script to run after logon that removes them, but that's kind of avoiding the issue. Have a chat to your AD team to see if you can be put in a different OU where the policy that puts them there doesn't apply (or to add an exclusion for your PC/user)

Comment: Or, just put the icons in a folder on your desktop that can still run as you need to. That is what I do for Mapping and Server shortcuts that need to run.

Comment: @Smock I wrote a PowerShell script before I made this question that runs at startup and checks for the icons then deletes them. The problem is that AD recognizes that the icons are gone during the night and restarts my PC to sync. In the morning my PC is now slow since I have to login and let things load instead of just unlocking my account, and on top of that the icons are back! So I ditched the script idea in favor of hiding the icons. Client/Server team handles AD and they won't make an AD exception, they're too busy. Need a work-around.

Comment: @John If I put the icons in a folder, AD notices that they have been moved (not DIRECTLY on the desktop). It then forces my PC to restart and puts the icons back. And now I have a slow PC in the morning due to the restart.

Comment: Hmm. Can you just add the '*hidden*' attribute to them? As long as you don't have '*show hidden items*' turned on, that should work

Comment: @Smock I tried that as well, but it just showed them as translucent icons. 'show hidden items' is not an option for me, even with local admin privileges, so that must be locked down in AD.

Comment: If on Windows 10, try to move the icons to a [virtual desktop](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-multiple-desktops-windows-10).

Comment: @harrymc I don't know how AD will handle that, but it's worth a try. Thank you for the suggestion. I will let you know if it works or not tomorrow morning after AD has had a chance to check for offending users.

Comment: And as I mentioned, my current solution is using the original (free) version of fences, although it's not perfect. Here's a vid of fences hiding and revealing my icons after double clicking on the desktop, and the whole "not being able to drag icons after installing fences" issue.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ss5kVjh14Omq0-QpON8bkDXOOfP-uc-T/view

Comment: @harrymc So it turns out the virtual desktops differ only in which windows are active. Adding or removing a desktop file applies to each virtual desktop, so there is no way to hide a file on a different virtual desktop. For now I will be sticking with the free original version of Fences.